# Is there any way/tool to open a console executable and then the console stays open?

Tags: windows-7, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent the command prompt from closing after execution?](https://superuser.com/questions/306167/how-to-prevent-the-command-prompt-from-closing-after-execution)

When I open an exe using the windows explorer, the console opens and closes. Is there any way or tool to the console stays open when I double click on the executable ?