# How to choose if you want to close the command prompt window or not running a .exe or .bat file?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010, cmd.exe, c#

I have a program written in C#, console application. A .exe file is created and when executing the command window opens, writes the output and closes as usual.
My problem is that I may need to see the output in the cmd (not always).
Is there any command (as I call my exe file through cmd in order not to close the command prompt that specific time only)??

Comment: To do this **programmatically**, you need to check whether or not you are running the program in a debugger (in the latter, sometimes the console window is displayed).  You can simply add a prompt when your program finishes telling the user to "Press any key to exit." and then simply close your program after the user enters *anything*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (calling as my_command.bat):

```
@echo off 

my_command.exe

pause
```

Comment: Thanks. This stops my cmd to close. But then I have to create 2 .bat files: 1 with the code above if I want to run without closing the cmd, and 1 (plain) if I do not the console output to be shown.
What is the purpose of '@echo off' by the way? It prevents **pause** to be printed to the cmd?
I've been looking for a week for an answer like yours. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to make the batch file more comfortable you can ask whether stop or not like here: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-Options-or-Choices-in-a-Batch-File

Answer (score 0):

Try the answer on [How to prevent the command prompt from closing after execution?](https://superuser.com/questions/306167/how-to-prevent-the-command-prompt-from-closing-after-execution)

This should give you the ability to choose what you want to do with the command prompt, after command execution.