# Keeping command prompt from closing after executing JScript

Tags: windows-10, command-line, script, javascript

I have a .js file that I am not allowed to modify. I can execute it by opening cmd.exe and entering the following:

```
cscript my_script.js
```

When I do that, the script runs to completion, and once it is done, it keeps the command prompt open so that I can read its output.

Since I don't want to go through those steps every time I need to execute a .js file, I rick clicked `my_script.js`, selected the "Open with" option, and set cscript.exe as the default program to run .js files.

After doing that, I am now able execute `my_script.js` by double clicking it. This is exactly what I wanted, but a new issue has arisen: once `my_script.js` finishes executing, the command prompt where the output is displayed closes automatically.

I have read the answers to [other](https://superuser.com/questions/306167/how-to-prevent-the-command-prompt-from-closing-after-execution) questions that describe how to fix this issue, but none of them apply to my particular situation (I am not allowed to modify the .js file).

Is there a way to keep the command prompt open after the .js file finishes executing?

Comment: How about outputting the script result into a text file? So make a batch file that has cscript my_script.js >> C:\temp\output.log and then you can read the output.log at your leisure?

Comment: You may find [SS64's reference page on `CMD`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) to be useful, specifically the `/K` switch.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple batch file that will open the command prompt, run your script and pauses after executing so that you can read the output.

Open a text editor and enter the following lines:

```
@ECHO OFF
cscript my_script.js
pause
```

Then save this as a .bat file. When you want to run the script you can simply run the batch file. The above example assumes that the batch file resides in the same folder as the script. Otherwise use:

```
cscript "\\yourpath\my_script.js"
```